# Get SVN URL of removed git-svn file

Tags: git-svn

I would like to track a removed file as far back in history as possible, while using git-svn on a *subdirectory* of the SVN repository.

1. Using `git log --full-history -- path/to/removed_file.py`, I can get see the history starting with the time the file was moved into the subdirectory I checked out using git-svn.
2. I can see which SVN revision that was in the git-svn commit message postfix, so I would now like to use `svn log <full_url>@revision` to see the rest of the history.
3. I know that I could use `git svn info --url path/to/existing_file.py` to see the required full SVN url, but what is a quick (ideally scriptable) way of **getting the SVN URL of a file that is no longer in the repository**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To git, it doesn't matter much that a file `foo/bar.py` is removed in `HEAD` — as long as you have it in history, you can view every past version of it.

For clarity of concreteness, I'll take [this git-svn repo](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/lnt) from the LLVM project as an example. There, the file `docs/todo.rst` has been deleted in svn revision 308987, git commit `fb572868…` and is absent in `master`.

Let's first init a local clone.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/llvm-mirror/lnt && cd lnt
Cloning into 'lnt'...
...
$ git svn init https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lnt/trunk
$ git update-ref refs/remotes/git-svn refs/remotes/origin/master
$ 
$ #-- ask svn info of anything to check setup and/or force laziness
$ git svn info --url README.md
Rebuilding .git/svn/refs/remotes/git-svn/.rev_map.91177308-0d34-0410-b5e6-96231b3b80d8 ...
r154126 = 3c3062527ac17b5fac440c55a3e1510d0ab8c9d9
r154135 = 82a95d29ac7d25c355fbd0898a44dc3e71a75fd8
...
r374687 = 446f9a3b651086e87684d643705273ef78045279
r374824 = 8c57bba3687ada10de5653ae46c537e957525bdb
Done rebuilding .git/svn/refs/remotes/git-svn/.rev_map.91177308-0d34-0410-b5e6-96231b3b80d8
https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lnt/trunk/README.md
```

So it gives back the `README.md` URL as expected. Now let's try the case of a deleted file:

```
$ git svn info --url docs/todo.rst
svn: 'docs/todo.rst' is not under version control
```

Fails, just like you say. [`man git-svn`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) says that `info` *Does not currently support a -r/--revision argument.*

OK then, let's try emulating what it does, first by hand.

`https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lnt/trunk/README.md?r=374824` — this is the URL for given file at given revision.

Our vanished `docs/todo.rst` is available at https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lnt/trunk/docs/todo.rst?p=308986 Notice the decrement: per `git show fb572868 | grep git-svn-id`, `docs/todo.rst` is *already* deleted in r308987 — so we request r308986.

On to scripting it... rather simple job.

```
git-svn-oldinfo () {
  relfname="$1"
  git log -n1 -- "$relfname" \
    | awk '/git-svn-id:/ {sub(/@/, " ", $2); print $2}' \
    | { read baseurl rev; echo "${baseurl}/${relfname}?p=$((rev-1))"; }
}

#-- test:
$ git-svn-oldinfo docs/todo.rst
https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lnt/trunk/docs/todo.rst?p=308986
```

Quick-n-dirty but tested — you're welcome to adjust & extend as needed.

---

*Edit*

Despite `git log` being a "porcelain" command (i.e. not really designed for scripting), it's quite possible to parse out the filenames from it too, if you're to query by globs like `**/removed_file.py`:

```
git-svn-oldinfo-glob () {
  fileglob="$1"
  git log -n1 --stat --format=oneline -- "$fileglob" \
    | { read commit msg; \
        read fullname _remainder_dummy; \
        git cat-file -p $commit \
          | tail -n1 \
          | awk '/git-svn-id:/ {sub(/@/, " ", $2); print $2}' \
          | { read baseurl rev; echo "${baseurl}/${fullname}?p=$((rev-1))"; } \
      }
}

#-- test:
$ git-svn-oldinfo-glob '**/todo.rst'
https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lnt/trunk/docs/todo.rst?p=308986
```

Take it with a grain of salt: it'll probably break in hilarious ways or output garbage if the glob matches multiple files, non-removed files, files with whitespace in the name, etc.

As always, check out [`man git-log`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) and customize as needed.

Comment: So, the "let's try emulating what it does" implicitly contains the first partial answer: We need to work without `git svn info`.

Comment: Then, you're basically parsing the output of `git log`, but I have another problem: `git log` supports globbing, which makes it possible to search for the history of a file of which one knows only the filename (or part of the path, in general). Example: `git log --full-history -- **/removed_file.py`; I guess I will have to look for a way to configure `git log` output to give me the path. Thank you for looking into this!

Comment: @hans_meine ah yes, I see the problem. Code updated with another version.

Comment: Re "work without `git svn info`": I'd push that statement much further; abandon `svn` altogether if you can. It's past-century technology. Git can do everything svn does; and then much more, and then much faster. My please to help!